# Co-recursion in Swift without forward function declarations

Tags: swift, recursion, forward-declaration

Swift has no mechanism for *forward function declarations* (as far as I can find) so I was wondering how one defines simple co-recursive functions. For example, a simple scheme for drawing the [Dragon Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) could use the following co-recursive functions `X` and `Y`:

```
func dragon(levels : Int) {

  func X(_ d : Int) {    // call's Y()
     if d > 0 {
         X(d - 1)
         turn(90)
         Y(d - 1)
         drawForward()
         turn(90)
     }
   }

   func Y(_ d : Int) {    // calls X()
     if d > 0 {
        turn(-90)
        drawForward()
        X(d - 1)
        turn(-90)
        Y(d - 1)
     }
   }

   drawForward()  // put these two statements above the definition
   X(levels)      // of 'X' and you get "use of 'X' before definition          
 }                // error."
```

I suppose I could pull this off somehow using protocols. But how do you solve this chicken-and-egg problem without forward declarations or incomplete types in Swift?

*Edit:* Code above is OK, but if you move the bottom call `X(levels)` so that
it occurs before the definition of `X` you get the error "Use of
local variable 'X' before its declaration". This seems strange
since you are defining `dragon` and `X(levels)` won't actually be
called until later (when `dragon` is actually called).

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Swift 3.1 (after adding stubs for `drawForward` and `turn`).

Comment: Unlike C, Swift doesn't require declarations in any particular order. You can use what you've written without doing anything special.

Comment: Hmmm... Xcode gives me "Use of local variable 'Y' before is declaration".

Comment: @wcochran What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: @Hamish -- Swift 3.1. What I find is you can *not* actually call a function that has not been defined yet -- for example, if you move the last two statements in the `dragon` function so that they occur *before* the definitions of `X` and `Y' then you get the error "Use of local variable 'X' before its declaration. This seems a little strange.

Comment: @wcochran Yeah, I will agree the rules are a bit inconsistent – but of course the example you give can be solved trivially, so it's really not much of a problem.